# How to get direct url of video from youtube url?

Tags: javascript, node.js, video, youtube, discord.js

I'm creating a bot in Discord.JS (it's a library for Node.JS) and I would like to add a music module to it. Discord.JS can play videos in formats like .wav, .mp4 etc. in voice channels. I would like to add a possibility for users to just type a YouTube url of a video to play it. Is there any possibility to get a video's url from an YouTube url by an API or any other way?

Comment: What did you investigate?

Comment: @Jeroen Heier I found a library from the same author as the author of the library from @Poootaatoooo - https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core (ytdl is command line, that one is for scripts), that can be used for that purpose.

It can be used like that: 
`const audio_stream = ytdl("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=some_id");
voice_handler = voice_connection.playStream(audio_stream);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Youtube API to play just audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36377590/using-youtube-api-to-play-just-audio)

Comment: get each video qualities from youtube get_video_info [PHP]
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55078023/signature-issue-when-i-want-to-get-a-direct-url-from-youtube-via-php/55250737#55250737

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used to be able to get it pretty easily with `youtube.com/get_video?video_id=...` but that was like 5+ years ago, now I think it uses some weird stream thing.

I don't think Youtube's official API lets you download videos or get a URL. Also, you should probably take a look at section 5B of the [YouTube TOS](https://www.youtube.com/t/terms)

> You shall not download any Content unless you see a “download” or similar link displayed by YouTube on the Service for that Content.

But anyway, one method I know is [youtube-dl](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/), but I'm pretty sure it's only for python. There seem to be a few node wrappers online though ([ex.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-dl))

I've also found a node.js youtube downloader, [ytdl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ytdl). Last update was 9 days ago so it should probably be working fine with the current system. You should be able to use `-o filename` or `--output filename` to download it, or `--print-url` to get a direct video url.

Answer (score -1):

You could use FFMPEG to download video and then play that file

Comment: Example: user types YouTube url (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=somevideo) and I want to get video's url from it (https://www.youtube.com/videos/some_video.mp4).